# How to run 'android' under windows 7

Tags: android

I have installed android sdk under Windows 7. But when I run it, I get the following error saying xcopy is not recognized as an command.

How can I resolve it?

Thank you.

```
C:\>android.bat
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to call android.bat?

Just start the 'SDK Manager' from the windows start menu.

Or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah. SDK Manager from start menu works. I just want to know how can I run it from command line.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. But why would you want to do that? (just curious)